# el indice 2 fuera de intervalo

Tags: javafx

Hola estoy tratando de correr un software pero al tratar de realizar la ejecución me sale un error de consola: el indice 2 fuera de intervalo.

mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void seleccionanombre() {

    ObservableList <Persona> busqueda =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     String consulta="select * from cliente where nombre like ?" ;
     String nombre = bq.getText();
     Connection conn=null;{

          try {

              conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
              PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
              ps.setString(1, nombre);
              ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();

             while ( rs.next() ) 
              {
                 busqueda.add(new Persona(
                         (rs.getString("nombre")),
                         (rs.getString("apellido")),
                         (rs.getInt("id"))
                         ));

              }

          } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          tablacliente.setItems(busqueda); 
     }

}

public void seleccionapellido() {
    ObservableList <Persona> busquedape =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     String consulta2="select * from cliente where apellido like ? " ;
     String apellido = bq.getText();
     Connection conn=null;{
          try {

              conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
              PreparedStatement ps2 =conn.prepareStatement(consulta2);
              ps2.setString(2, apellido);
              ResultSet rs =ps2.executeQuery();

             while ( rs.next() ) 
              {
                 busquedape.add(new Persona(
                         rs.getString("nombre"),
                         rs.getString("apellido"),
                         rs.getInt("id")
                         ));

              }

          } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          tablacliente.setItems(busquedape); 
     }

}
```

Comment: funciono? el codigo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que solo tienes un simbolo, en el código ?

```
String consulta2="select * from cliente where apellido like ?";
```

entonces deberías asignar el parametro uno:

```
ps2.setString(1, apellido);
```

Comment: Debo quitar el "?" Del codigo?

Comment: no!, debes cambiar el indice como lo indique. Cambiar el parametro en ve de 2 , poner 1

Comment: usualmente el statememt like ademas contiene '"%%", debes revisar eso tambien

Comment: @Rafael me cuentas luego de que pruebes

Comment: JPRLCol dime si estoy en lo correcto

Comment: JPRLCol corregi el codigo pero ahora me sale otro error: El valor no está configurado para el número de parámetro 1. que puede ser?

Comment: Veo q tienes dos interrogaciones seguidas en el query

Comment: mejore el codigo pero sigue igual, me sigue arrojando el indice 2 esta fuera de intervalo. ayudame porfa

Comment: actualiza el codigo en la pregunta